# Live changing bjobs output

Tags: parallelism, high-performance, platform-lsf

When using LSF command `bjobs`, I would like to get instantly changing output if I submit another job, because I feel stressful to run the same command again and again. I would like something like `top` refreshing the output of the list of processes.

[image: I have to re-run the command to see updates]

In `top` that is not needed, it autorefreshes again and again.

I would like to auto-refresh the output of the `bjobs` command automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`watch bjobs` will run and update the output for display every two seconds (by default).